# Unable to scrape snapdeal data using scrapy

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

The output while trying to scrape snapdeal data is as follows:

```
scrapy shell "https://www.snapdeal.com"

response.text

u'<HTML><HEAD>\n<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>Access Denied</H1>\n \nYou don\'t have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;snapdeal&#46;com&#47;" on this server.<P>\nReference&#32;&#35;18&#46;1dd70b17&#46;1514632273&#46;17456300\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n'
```

Any help?

Comment: This is scraping protection, they don't want you to scrape it. You need to either use proxies and also use some other user agent, scrapy shell will use the default scrapy user agent

Comment: You have to copy entire request and mimic that in scrapy,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use `User-Agent` then I get correct page

```
scrapy shell

fetch("https://www.snapdeal.com", headers={'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0"})

response.text
```

Or using script

```
import scrapy
#from scrapy.commands.view import open_in_browser

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    start_urls = ['https://www.snapdeal.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        #open_in_browser(response)

        for item in response.xpath('//*[@class="catText"]/text()').extract():
            print(item)

# --- it runs without project ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: it is minimal `User-Agent` which mostly works. If you need real `User-Agent` from your browser then visit [http://httpbin.org/user-agent](http://httpbin.org/user-agent)